# Assign Column Name for Simple Coalesce Statement

Tags: sql, coalesce

While attempting to create a list of all ID's made since _____ I am able to get the results I want from the following:

```
DECLARE @BoID varchar(max)

SELECT @BoID = COALESCE(@BoID + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(ApplicationID AS varchar(10)) 
FROM BoList as "ID"
WHERE CreatedDate > '2017-07-01 18:14:09.210'
```

However, I am having issues with establishing a column name for the above statement. Where does the `as "ID"` need to be located at in order to give the above result a column name of "ID"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the query stands now, you are giving the table BoList an alias of "ID" instead of the column.  Since you are selecting the value into a variable there is no output.  You can do it like this...

```
SELECT COALESCE(@BoID + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(ApplicationID AS varchar(10)) as "ID"
FROM BoList 
WHERE CreatedDate > '2017-07-01 18:14:09.210'
```

Or if you really do need to stash the value in a variable to return later as part of another query...

```
DECLARE @BoID varchar(max)

SELECT @BoID = COALESCE(@BoID + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(ApplicationID AS varchar(10)) 
FROM BoList
WHERE CreatedDate > '2017-07-01 18:14:09.210' 

SELECT @BoID AS "ID", other columns... FROM whatever
```